# Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA: What should I carefully read through to make sure no malicious code/scripts will be executed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I'm getting back to developing android apps recently and the latest Android Studio is giving me this pop up upon launch:

[image: Example Pic]

Note the picture is actually for Maven on IntelliJ IDEA but my environment is actually Android Studio, but the message if my memory serves, is virtually the same.

I'm opening a project from github with over 100 stars so it's relatively low risk but still I want to be cautious. As someone who isn't super knowledgeable about the IJ IDE, can someone tell me what are the coding files and scripts that I should sift through to make sure there is no danger in compiling the project and beyond?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the repo link?

Comment: Sure? Are you trying to vet the repo for me? LOL

Comment: here you go: https://github.com/freyskill/SerialPortHelper

Comment: thanks for the repo. I will check the files and let you know

Comment: the files seem ok. You can go with `Trust Project`. I tried opening the project in my `AS` and tried to run. It works good! You can go with it

Comment: Thank you! I'll also do a run myself.